# How to adjust table in modal bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatable

I've this code in my datatable:

[image]

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#LogsTable').DataTable({
                "order": [[3, 'desc']],
                paging: false,
                //"scrollY": false,
                //"scrollX": true,
                searching: false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "columnDefs": [
                    { "width": "20%", "targets": 4 }
                ]
            });
        });
```

my problem is how to put right the datable inside my modal bootstrap? 
insert a scroll in X maybe. Dont know. 
Thanks

Comment: Add your HTML code here

Comment: Wrap your table in a div with `overflow: auto;` set to create an overflow wrapper that will add scrollbars when the table overflows the modal

Answer (score 0):

add `model-lg` class with modal-dialog

```html
<div class="modal" id="email" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog model-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
            </div>
       </div>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try add "table-responsive" class to your table. Bootstrap 4 have it for sure, but dunno about lower versions.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: here is a link to documentation: [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables)